# Multiple Magento Stores sharing inventory generates a new URL from the shopping cart

Tags: php, magento

We have three stores within Magento EE. When the site was set-up, inventory was dumped into "All Store Views" versus in each individual store. Having said that, some inventory is sold across all three sites, and all three sites share the same user login and checkout process. But what happens now is, if you add a store-specific item to your cart (from Store A), then head over to one of the other two sites' shopping carts (Store B or C) and click the product link, it essentially replicates the product page (from A) on the (Store B or C) domain. The URL path is the same, and all on-page content is exactly the same.

Does this issue stem from all inventory being under All Stores? Or can this be fix, so if you have an item from Store A in your Store B shopping cart, that the link points back to its origin in Store A?

Comment: How did you specify that the product is specific to only a specific store?

Comment: Since it's under All Stores, it's only specified via the categories. All SKU are available to be sold across all 3 sites, but categorization limits it to specific stores.

Comment: I have magento enterprise myself so i checked, categories are not store-specific, you can chose not to show the category in a specific store through the frontend/theme, but as far as magento understands, the product and the category are available on ALL stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Magento's default implementation goes, products are NOT store-specific, also categories are NOT store-specific, you may however choose to change the visibility of the product per store.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed these are now being picked up in our sitemaps and being cached/indexed by Google. Sounds like setting these stores as websites, and re-importing the products into their specific store views may be the way to go?

Comment: That should work since the concept of websites is to have separate entities.